# How to use something like LIKE IN in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Here is my part of code

```
if (!isset($_GET['jenis'])) {
$jenis =  [] ;
} else {
$jenis = $_GET['jenis'];
}

$sql= 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE nama LIKE "'.$cari.'%" ORDER BY '.$urutkan.' LIMIT '.$this_page_first_result.','.$results_per_page;


<h3 class="sidebar-title">jenis</h3>
    <div class="sidebar-list">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="21" <?php if (in_array("21",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> Khusus Pria  </a> </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="22" <?php if (in_array("22",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> Khusus Wanita </a> </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="23" <?php if (in_array("23",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> Campuran </a> </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="24" <?php if (in_array("24",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 2 Lantai </a> </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="25" <?php if (in_array("25",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 3 Lantai </a> </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jenissss();" name="jenis[]" value="26" <?php if (in_array("26",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 4 Lantai atau Lebih </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

in sql jenis stored like 
    AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF

```
  example :
   data 1= AA,BB

   data 2= CC,DD

   data 3= AA,DD,EE,FF

   data 4= DD,EE,FF

   data 5= BB,FF
```

if i click AA it will show data 1 as result.

if i click AA and BB it will show data 1, data 3, and data 5 as result.

if i click AA and BB and DD it will show data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, and data 5 as result.

if i click EE data 3 and data 4 will show

My hope the output will be

```
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE nama LIKE "'.$cari.'%" AND jenis LIKE IN '.$jenis.' ORDER BY '.$urutkan.' LIMIT '.$this_page_first_result.','.$results_per_page;
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com first learn about SQL injection to prevent them if you don't want your whole database to be deleted by a user.

Comment: Start by normalizing that schema and use a table with a row for every `jenis` instead of using a comma separated string list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sqlJenis = "('" . implode("','", $jenis) . "')";

$sql= 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE nama LIKE "'.$cari.'%" AND jenis IN '.$sqlJenis.' ORDER BY '.$urutkan.' LIMIT '.$this_page_first_result.','.$results_per_page;
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) about IN statement.

Note: As @Twinfriends said, you should learn about SQL injection (security) before using this code for real in production.

Comment: it work, but not work well. example,  data 6 = AA,AB,AC,AD,AE  if i only click AC or only click AB it didn't show, but if i click AA and AB or AA and AB and AC it show

Comment: its like sql =  AND jenis LIKE IN %'.$sqlJenis.'%